# Search and Validate JSON objects with nested structure

Tags: java, json, list, spring-boot, arraylist

I have a request and response JSON object as below

```
{
   "request":{
      "name":"Ryan",
      "title":"TEMP",
      "workGroups":[
         {
            "home":[
               {
                  "groupName":"Group 1",
                  "groupValue":"5"
               },
               {
                  "groupName":"Group 3",
                  "groupValue":"6"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   "response":{
      "name":"Ryan",
      "title":"TEMP",
      "workGroups":[
         {
            "home":[
               {
                  "groupName":"Group 3",
                  "groupValue":"6"
               },
               {
                  "groupName":"Group 1",
                  "groupValue":"5"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I am trying to compare the nested values in "home" field inside "workGroups" in request against the same fields in response, and then process a validation after that, How can i compare the values inside it considering the order of values in home field can be in different order between request and response, is there a way to do it with minimal loops?

Comment: I think the approach I would use would be to deserialize to objects, and then `workGroups` should be a collection, at which point you could try to a `Collections.disjoint` which will return `true` if the collections share no elements, so in your case you would be looking for `false` as the result.  Apache Collections may have more appropriate methods such as intersection that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have both objects deserialized, you could easily flatten the two lists containing the inner most `home` objects like so:

```
List<HomeExample> responseHomes = response
    .getWorkGroups()
    .stream()
    .map(WorkgroupExample::getHome)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<HomeExample> requestHomes = payload
    .getWorkGroups()
    .stream()
    .map(WorkgroupExample::getHome)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

That way you should end up with two distinct lists, one containing the `home` entries of the `request` object and one containing the `home` entries of the `response` object.

With that on hand, you could then compare the two lists ignoring order, either manually to using something like `CollectionUtils#isEqualCollection`.